# Performance impact of virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, performance, real-time, virtual-inheritance

I am considering using virtual inheritance in a real-time application. Does using virtual inheritance have a performance impact similar to that of calling a virtual function? The objects in question would only be created at start up but I'm concerned if all functions from the hierarchy would be dispatched via a vtable or if only those from the virtual base class would be.

Comment: Unless you are using multiple inheritance, there isn't really a need to use virtual inheritance.

Comment: @ZacHowland, unless you are using mocking with Google Test. (gtest)

Comment: @Amigable:  There is no "unless".  When using Google Test, you still only use virtual inheritance when dealing with multiple inheritance.

Comment: @ZacHowland, my mistake in that case.  I thought it was a requisite to able to to mock classes. But I haven't actually started using it yet... so what do I know.

Comment: The Google Test framework allows you to create mock objects for non-pure-abstract classes, so when you inherit from these classes, you can run into a diamond situation (multiple inheritance) which would require virtual inheritance.  It is still a better practice to use pure-abstract (aka "interfaces") and mock the interface with a new implementation, however.  It will make your test code easier to write and maintain (in addition to making your actual code easier to write and maintain).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Common implementations will make access to ***data members*** of virtual base classes use an additional indirection.

As James points out in his comments, calling a member function of a base class in a multiple inheritance scenario will need adjustment of the `this` pointer, and if that base class is virtual, then the offset of the base class sub-object in the derived class's object depends on the dynamic type of the derived class and will need to be calculated at runtime.

Whether this has any visible performance impact on real-world applications depends on many things:

- Do virtual bases ***have data members*** at all? Often, it's abstract base classes that need to be derived from virtually, and abstract bases that have any data members are often a code smell anyway.
- Assuming you have virtual bases with data members, are those accessed ***in a critical path***? If a user clicking on some button in a GUI results in a few dozen additional indirections, nobody will notice.
- What would be the ***alternative*** if virtual bases are avoided? Not only might the design be inferior, it is also likely that the alternative design has a performance impact, too. It has to achieve the same goal, after all, and TANSTAAFL. Then you traded one performance loss for another plus an inferior design.

---

Additional note: Have a look at Stan Lippmann's *[Inside the C++ Object Model](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201834545)*, which answers such questions quite thoroughly.

Comment: TO clarify, only calls to the virtual base classes members/functions result in additional indirection?

Comment: @Graeme: I'm certainly no expert in this area, but I don't see how calls to virtual base class member _functions_ would result in a performance loss. They are either dispatched statically (`B::f()`) or dynamically through the derived class's virtual table, just like member functions of non-virtual bases. ICBWT.

Comment: @sbi:  If the function is not virtual, then the function to be called can be selected statically, but the `this` pointer must be computed [or looked up] at runtime, right?

Comment: @James: Oh, that's right, I forgot `this` pointer adjustment. But that's due to _multiple_ inheritance, whether virtual or not, or is there some additional cost I'm forgetting about?

Comment: @sbi:  I think it's the difference between a computation and a look up.  In nonvirtual multiple inheritance, you can add a known offset to whatever pointer you have to obtain the `this` pointer.  In virtual multiple inheritance, you have to go look up (at runtime) where the base class subobject is to get the `this` pointer.  A lookup is "more expensive" than an addition, but how relevant that difference is depends on the application:  as you say; unless this is a time-critical operation in a program with real-time performance constraints, it's not going to matter.

Comment: @sbi: neat acronym `TANSTAAFL` :p

Comment: @James: Ah, that's right! Then each call to a virtual function of the base class will result in such a lookup, right?

Comment: @Matthieu: I assumed that to be well known. Isn't it?  (Maybe I've caught it reading Larry Niven or whoever used it in their books?)

Comment: @sbi: I knew the sentence behind it (first read it on Sutter's blog) but didn't mapped the acronym instantly... but Google did :)

Comment: @Matthieu: Yeah, [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_ain%27t_no_such_thing_as_a_free_lunch) it became popular through Heinlein's _the Moon is a Harsh Mistress_. That would fit my reading habits, too. `:)`

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the following large scale experimental study published OOPSLA'96. I am copy pasting a bibtex entry, the abstract and a link to the paper. I would consider this the most comprehensive experimental study on the topic to date.

```
@article{driesen1996direct,
  title={{The direct cost of virtual function calls in C++}},
  author={Driesen, K. and H{\\"o}lzle, U.},
  journal={ACM Sigplan Notices},
  volume={31},
  number={10},
  pages={306--323},
  issn={0362-1340},
  year={1996},
  publisher={ACM}
}
```

**Abstract:**
We study the direct cost of virtual function
calls in C++ programs, assuming the standard
implementation using virtual function tables. We
measure this overhead experimentally for a number of
large benchmark programs, using a combination of
executable inspection and processor simulation. Our
results show that the C++ programs measured spend a
median of 5.2% of their time and 3.7% of their
instructions in dispatch code. For “all virtuals”
versions of the programs, the median overhead rises to
13.7% (13% of the instructions). The “thunk” variant
of the virtual function table implementation reduces
the overhead by a median of 21% relative to the
standard implementation. On future processors, these
overheads are likely to increase moderately

http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~urs/oocsb/papers/oopsla96.pdf

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if compiler optimizations have rendered this study obsolete. It was published in 1996.

Comment: Um. But the question was about ___virtual inheritance___, not about ___virtual functions___.

Comment: This study was done on processors from 1995.  Only 32-bit processors were studied (having 256K cache (8K instruction cache)).  Current desktop processors are 64-bit with 8MB cache.   The Intel Pentium Pro studied did not have MMX.  Might as well compare Windows 95 to Windows 10 (rhetorical comment; please don't).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you mean virtual inheritance? If so, it's identical to the cost of a normal virtual function call. The vtable chained search just follows a specified path.

You said that this was at startup. Your disk overhead (from simply loading your code into memory) is likely to require orders of magnitude more time than the half-dozen instructions or so for vtable lookups. I'd be somewhat surprised if you could profile this and detect a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Without inspecting compilation or runtime details, based on my test using GNU C++17, accessing data member in virtual base class has no performance inpact.