# diamond inheritance - Passing leaf class object as parameter in place of root class

Tags: c++, inheritance, diamond-problem

i have a program with the following inheritance structure

```
                       List
                   /         \
          DoublyLinkedList   CircularlyLinkedList
                   \          /
                CircularlyDoublyLinkedList
```

In the `List` class (which is fully abstract) I have a pure virtual function

```
     int virtual insert(List **head, int position) = 0;
```

which I have overridden in the `DoublyLinkedList` and `CircularlyLinkedList` classes.
In order to resolve ambiguity in the `CircularlyDoublyLinkedList` class, I explicitly specify which version of the `insert()` function to inherit using the scope resolution operator `::`, for example: `DoublyLinkedList::insert(..)`
My problem is that this statement

```
    List *cdll_head = new CircularlyDoublyLinkedList();
```

throws an error

```
    "cannot convert CircularlyDoublyLinkedList* to  List*"
```

when I change the statement as

```
    CircularlyDoublyLinkedList *cdll_head = new CircularlyDoublyLinkedList();
```

I get another error as `insert(...)` accepts a parameter of type `List**`

How do I resolve this problem without a cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using multiple inheritance with diamond-shaped structures, you should use **virtual** inheritance.

I assume your code looks a bit like this:

```
class List {
...
};

class DoublyLinkedList: public List {
...
};

class CircularlyLinkedList: public List {
...
};

class CircularlyDoublyLinkedList: public DoublyLinkedList, public CircularlyLinkedList {
...
};

void doStuff() {
    List* aList = new CircularlyDoublyLinkedList();
    ...
}
```

which produces the following error:

```
ambiguous conversion from derived class 'CircularlyDoublyLinkedList' to base class 'List':
    class CircularlyDoublyLinkedList -> class DoublyLinkedList -> class List
    class CircularlyDoublyLinkedList -> class CircularlyLinkedList -> class List
```

If you change the inheritance of DoublyLinkedList and CircularlyLinkedList to virtual public like follows:

```
class DoublyLinkedList: virtual public List {
...
};

class CircularlyLinkedList: virtual public List {
...
};

class CircularlyDoublyLinkedList: public DoublyLinkedList, public CircularlyLinkedList {
...
};
```

everything should compile properly. However, there is an [additional performance cost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899657/performance-impact-of-virtual-inheritance). I would suggest using a fully abstract list interface that would be inherited by all your list classes, and composition to allow implementation reuse.

Comment: thanks a lot for the patient reply.My list base class is fully astract with all functions as pure virtual.I have done something like DoublyLinked::insert() in the CircularlyDoubly insert function,so is virtual inheritance necessary?